# granting select to mysql.proc in mysql engine

Tags: mysql, mariadb, aws-aurora-serverless

I Have taken DB dump of Maria DB, and trying to restore it on mysql engine, it is failing with some syntax checks.

the below procedure is failing with error not sure how can I correct the query

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 23872: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if not exists idx_company_reviews on company_reviews (review_to_company_id);
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `createCompanyReviews`()
begin
create temporary table if not exists company_reviews (
SELECT review_to_company_id,
ifnull(sum(rate) / count(rate), 0) as average,
count(rate)                        as amount
FROM (
SELECT
review_to_company_id,
ifnull(ceiling(avg(nullif(crc.rate_amount, 0))), cr.initial_rate_amount) AS rate
FROM T_COMPANY_REVIEW cr
LEFT JOIN T_COMPANY_REVIEW_CATEGORY crc ON cr.id = crc.company_review_id
WHERE cr.published = TRUE
GROUP BY cr.id
UNION ALL
SELECT review_to_company_id, rate_amount as rate
FROM T_COMPANY_REFERENCE
WHERE rate_amount IS NOT NULL
AND published = true
);
```

Comment: Why does a user need to access mysql.proc? mysql tables and views are system tables and shouldn't be touched.

Answer (score 1):

Tables and views from the mysql schema are system tables and shouldn't be touched at all.

If a  user needs to retrieve information/metadata for stored procedures it should be retrieved from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`. The are no special GRANTS required for accessing `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.